# Auto delete temp tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, temp-tables

In BigQuery lot of temp_table_* tables are created, this is clustering the datasets. Is there any way to delete these temp tables automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temp tables are created from one of the third party consumers, they are using Simba JDBC connector, which internally using the temp_table_ prefix.

Currently no option to set expire date for these tables, once they introduce the option we will leverage.

Reference:
https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/largeresulttable.htm

Answer (score 3):

On any a dataset you can set a default expiration time for any new table you create in it. Then everything will get deleted on schedule.

Same for tables, even at creation time you can set an automatic deletion date.

Now, who is creating these temp tables you see? I have no idea, I've never seen them.

I'm 99.9% sure these tables are not created by any process ran by Google. No one at Google would format dates in that way.